# saving relative values with cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

In MySQL I can do the following:

```
UPDATE table SET field=field+1 WHERE id=123
```

How do I do the same while using the CakePHP approach?

Tried the following:

```
$this->Model->id = 123;
$this->Model->save(array(
    'field' => '`field`+1',
));
```

The article [saving-your-data.html](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html) doesn't seem to cover that.

Also searched for [cakephp+update+relative](https://www.google.com/search?q=cakephp+update+relative), found nothing relevant.

**UPDATE** Right now I'm doing a direct update, it works but I was thinking there might be a better way

```
$this->Model->query("UPDATE ".$this->Model->useTable." SET field=field+1 WHERE id=123");
```

Comment: Remove ` symbol. And did you try like this?                                          $this->Model->save(array('field' =>'field+1'));

Comment: CakePHP is normally able to parse all those `\``, but I gave it a try. It resets the `INT` field to `0` which apparently means it still tries to save the textual value and fails to do that.

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->Model->updateAll(  
         array('Model.count' => 'Model.count + 1'),  
         array('Model.id' => 1)  

  );
```

Comment: thank you. will this update the record i need if i set `$this->Model->id = 123;` before executing `updateAll`? sorry should've pointed that out in the question

Comment: $this->Article->saveField('viewed', (int)$this->Article->field('viewed') + 1);